# IE11(in Outlook 2016 Desktop Client on Windows 10) - download files not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to download files in IE11(in Outlook 2016 Desktop Client on Windows 10), with the following piece of code:

```
 if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
     return navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
 }
```

The problem is that "msSaveBlob" property does not exist on navigator.
Note: This used to work until an update of windows10 to the newest version: 1903.
Also tried to use this library: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js,
but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN, [`navigator.msSaveBlob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/msSaveBlob) is obsolete and shouldn't be used in any (production) environment.

Another possible solution is to generate a data:URI, but unfortunately IE11 doesn't support this...

So, the (IMHO) only alternative is to generate the file server-side and send it to the client.

Comment: What do you mean by _generate the file server-side and send it to the client_?

Comment: You're trying to save a blob of information client-side (thus via the browser), but this solution is lacking support (see my answer). Therefore it's better to have the files you're trying to save available and ready to download on the server. If you want, for example, generate and save an image, it's better to have that image stored on a server in a way that you can download it directly.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure how can I download a file without using the browser. I have the file saved on server-side.

Comment: I have the file in memory, not as a file saved at the server side